# Formatting json strings in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a query that runs and creates a dataframe like below:

```
Group   Hour
G1        0
G1        4
G2        1
G3        5
```

I then write the dataframe to a json file using

```
out = df1.to_json(orient='records')[1:-1].replace('},{', '} {')
```

Currently my output looks like

```
{"Group":"G1","Hour":0} {"Group":"G2","Hour":4} {"Group":"G2","Hour":1}
```

It is a continuous stream of lines. I am trying to make each json document to be in a separate line like below:

```
{"Group":"G1","Hour":0} 
{"Group":"G2","Hour":4} 
{"Group":"G2","Hour":1}
```

Not sure whether there is a way to achieve this in Python. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you replacing `},{` with `} {` in the first place? You could easily use a `\n` newline instead of a space there of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `.replace('},{', '} {')` part to `.replace('},{', '}\n{')`?